# Is $\gcd(a^n-1,a^nm) = \gcd(a^n-1,m)?$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm, euclidean-algorithm

I came across this procedure while trying to solve $gcd((2^{100})-1,(2^{120})-1))$, the procedure yielded correct result.
E.g
$gcd((2^{120})-1,2^{100}-1))$
=$gcd((2^{100})-1,2^{120}-2^{100}))$
= $gcd((2^{100})-1,2^{20}-1))$
And I kept solving like this using repeated subtraction and the property mentioned in the question.

The answer is ***$2^{20}-1$***
So, by using Euclidean algorithm and other properties of gcd can we prove that $gcd((a^n)-1,a^n(m)) = gcd((a^n)-1,m))$

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: $\gcd(u,v)=1\implies\gcd(u,vm)=\gcd(u,m).$

Comment: Thanks,this works for the given scenario. Edited the question,hope it's understandable now. I believe the general equality given in the question holds because a^n and (a^n)-1 are coprimes.

Comment: You believe right, this was precisely the meaning of my comment and link to the duplicate.

Comment: Your edit should really be improved: [format your formulas](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) (look at the way I edited your title)